# Alinhar div em tamanhos iguais CSS

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte CSS:

```
.your-account-main-menu li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 12%;
    border: solid 1px #EDEDED;
}
```

E a seguinte estrutura

```
<ul class="your-account-main-menu">
    <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=='myaccount' && $this->uri->segment(2)=='creditcard') echo "class=\"active\""; ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('myaccount/creditcard'); ?>">
            <div class="text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-money fa-3x" data-original-title="" title=""></i><br>
                Credit Card
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>   

    <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=='myaccount' && $this->uri->segment(2)=='changepassword') echo "class=\"active\""; ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('myaccount/changepassword'); ?>">
            <div class="text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-lock fa-3x" data-original-title="" title=""></i><br>
                Change Password
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>   

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url("myaccount/logout"); ?>">
            <div class="text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-3x" data-original-title="" title=""></i><br>
                Exit
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>                       
</ul>
```

Porém, ao exibir fica dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso deixar no tamanho uniforme, porém, não quero definir altura e largura do mesmo tamanho *fixo*, como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: ja tentou com flexbox?

Comment: altera seu código com informacoes staticas para testar e te ajudar

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo Estas já são as informações estáticas.. :) E nunca tentei usar o flexbox.

Comment: é que essas informações por exemplo <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=='myaccount' && $this->uri->seg nõ carrega pra mim. mas tenta com flex. Se alterar a pergunta posso montar pra vc

Comment: Pode remover, não há problemas, isto é somente pra ajustar classe.